# Mass typo in questions and answers: "onlick" should be "onclick"

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, spelling, clean-up

<strike>https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=%22onlick%22</strike>

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22onlick%22

Over <strike>300</strike> 30 results with typo in title, editing is easy enough but I don't have time for proper edits in all of them. Also don't forget to close-vote questions where this typo is the error, as they're too localized.

Started to edit some, but anyone with some spare time is more than welcome to lend a hand. :)

Comment: That's a new API from Google - following Google Glass, they will be introducing Google Tongue.

Comment: @Oded I was thinking more of new Apps for smartphones with actual `onlick` events - for example letting you lick icecream! :D

Comment: @Oded can you do some magic to just rename this low level without editing or revisions? Don't think there's just yet any real use of the word "onlick". :)

Comment: There are other similar typo's too, but with not nearly as many results. Done a few - now if you could just get everybody else to do the same...

Comment: Don't do this one, as "onlick" is the bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108602/js-onclick-in-zend

Comment: @chuex Raises the question of whether that question is worth keeping around at all, to be honest.

Comment: I guess we need to be careful - found another where "onlick" is the bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685201/google-event-tracking-code-problems/15685363#15685363

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - True. Voted to close it since I don't have delete powers.

Comment: Most of the ones I'm seeing have the typo in comments or explanatory text, not in code, and probably aren't worth fixing IMO (unless there are other things to fix in the posts).

Comment: @Wooble yep seeing it now too. Changing to title only search then, as chue mentioned when there's such typo in code many times it's the core of the problem so can't be edited.